# currentchart.export compatibility excel 2010 vs 2003

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

I need to export a chart from excel. I did it in excel 2010 and worked fine, but, the application is needed in excel 2003 too. When I use the same code in 2003, the image is not exported right (it is a doughnut chart, and the "portions" are not well embedded).

This is the code i'm using:

```
Sheets("SLA Chart").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Dibujo")).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
Selection.Name = "imagen"
Selection.Copy
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Paste
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 282
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 213
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 40
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.8, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 275
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 175 'I can see here the image right
archivo = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator _
& "temp.gif"
ActiveChart.Export Filename:=archivo, FilterName:="GIF" 'The image is not well embedded
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveChart.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets("SLA Chart").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("imagen")).Delete
```

Comment: What happens when you export it to Jpg?

Comment: I tried to export to jpg and gif, but the same error occurs. I think the problem is due to is a group image (I try exporting each image, and excel do it right), but I need the group image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found other solution... you can copy the image as a bitmap, and then save it from the clipboard.

```
Sheets("SLA Chart").Select
'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Cuentakilometros")).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes(3).CopyPicture
ActiveSheet.Paste
imagen = Selection.Name
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

Clip2File

archivo = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\temp.bmp"
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(imagen)).Delete
```

Where Clip2file is a function obtained from the page http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-6046.html
(Solution of Killian thanks!!)

```
'##############################################
 '### Paste into a standard module - call Clip2File ###
 '##################################################

' Checks the clipboard for a bitmap
' If found, creates a standard Picture object from the
' clipboard contetnts and saves it to a file
' The code requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
' The code in this module has been derived primarily from _
' the PatsePicture sample on Stephen Bullen's Excel Page _
' - http://www.bmsltd.ie/Excel/Default.htm
'Windows API Function Declarations
Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" _
(ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" _
(ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" ( _
PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle _
As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
Private Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal handle _
As Long, _
ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, _
ByVal un2 As Long) As Long

'The API format types we need
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4


'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
Data1 As Long
Data2 As Integer
Data3 As Integer
Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

 'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
Size As Long
Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

Sub Clip2File()

    Dim strOutputPath As String, oPic As IPictureDisp

     'Get the filename to save the bitmap to
    strOutputPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.bmp"

     'Retrieve the picture from the clipboard...
    Set oPic = GetClipPicture()

     '... and save it to the file
    If Not oPic Is Nothing Then
        SavePicture oPic, strOutputPath
        'MsgBox "File saved: " & strOutputPath
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to retrieve bitmap from clipboard"
    End If
End Sub

Function GetClipPicture() As IPicture

    Dim h As Long, hpicavail As Long, hPtr As Long, _
    hPal As Long, hCopy As Long

     'Check if the clipboard contains a bitmap
    hpicavail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_BITMAP)

    If hpicavail <> 0 Then
         'Get access to the clipboard
        h = OpenClipboard(0&)
        If h > 0 Then
             'Get a handle to the image data
            hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)
            hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
             'Release the clipboard to other programs
            h = CloseClipboard
             'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into _
             'a Picture object and return it
            If hPtr <> 0 Then Set GetClipPicture = CreatePicture(hCopy, _
            0, CF_BITMAP)
        End If
    End If

End Function

Private Function CreatePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, _
    ByVal lPicType) As IPicture

     ' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
    Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As GUID, _
    IPic As IPicture

     'OLE Picture types
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1

     ' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With

     ' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo) ' Length of structure.
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP ' Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPic ' Handle to image.
        .hPal = 0 ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With

     ' Create the Picture object.
    r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)

     ' Return the new Picture object.
    Set CreatePicture = IPic

End Function
```